# How indent GNU style functions properly with VIM?

Tags: c, vim, indentation

I write my functions like,

```
static int
foo_bar(const char *string)
{
}
```

When I indent this using Vim, it does something like,

```
   static int
foo_bar(const char *string)
{
}
```

It adds some extra spaces before `static int`. How can I fix this?

Comment: You don't seem to want [GNU style](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indent_style#GNU_style), but something more like Allman. Not that I can see the appeal of either one, but that's your lookout.

Comment: What indent are you using? `filetype`?  `cindent`? `smartindent`?

Comment: I think I am using `filetype`. I have `filetype plugin indent on` in my `.vimrc`

Answer (score 0):

I found this just recently:

http://thisblog.runsfreesoftware.com/?q=2009/04/20/indent-gnu-style-vim

add this to your vimrc and reindent by typing `==`, of if you want, say, 5 lines indented type `5==`